# Angular : How to display data from Lov Item?

Tags: angular

I have a problem.

How to display data using *ngFor? I was doing it but data wasn't displaying. I am so confusedly because of im pretty new in Angular. Anyone can help me?

My View :

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="1000ms">
    <mat-tab label="Component">
         <div class="drag-list">
              <div class="drag-item" *ngFor="let components of filteredComponentLov" matRipple (click)="components.options.selected = !components.options.selected" [class.selected-item]="components.options.selected">{{components.description}}
              </div>
          </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Formula">
            <div class="drag-list">
                  <div class="drag-item" *ngFor="let formulas of filteredFormulaLov" matRipple (click)="formulas.options.selected = !formulas.options.selected" [class.selected-item]="formulas.options.selected">{{formulas.description}}
                  </div>
             </div>
      </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

> Data actually show in LogCat

any help will be appreciate

My Controller :

```
filteredComponentLov: LOVItem[] = [];
  filteredFormulaLov: LOVItem[] = [];
  filteredFunctionLov: LOVItem[] = [];


  filterComponentLov = "";
  filterFormulaLov = "";
  filterFunctionLov = "";

  constructor(
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public sharedService: SharedService,
    public metaService: MetaService,
    public bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    public salaryformulaService: SalaryFormulaService,
    public router: Router,
    private lovService: LOVService,
    public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
  ) {
    super();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(value => {
      const httpRequests: Observable<HttpResponse<any>>[] = [];

      httpRequests.push(this.metaService.get(0, "SalaryFormulaEntity"));

      httpRequests.push(this.lovService.predefined("LOV_SALARY_COMPONENT"));
      httpRequests.push(this.lovService.predefined("LOV_SALARY_FORMULA"));
      httpRequests.push(this.lovService.predefined("LOV_FUNCTION"));


            this.componentLov = this.lovResponse.lovResponseDetails[0].lovItems;
            this.formulaLov = this.lovResponse.lovResponseDetails[1].lovItems;
            this.functionLov = this.lovResponse.lovResponseDetails[2].lovItems;
});
```

Comment: What data is present please show your data

Comment: I don't think that you're that new that cannot even place a `console.log(filteredComponentLov);` in constructor and take the snapshot of your console and post it here!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you try to fetch data from array of variable `filteredComponentLov[] and filteredFormulaLov[]`
But that variable no data or your not assign the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch data from an array `filteredComponentLov and filteredFormulaLov`
but nowhere in your controller have you assigned them any values. You are trying to render an empty array in your html.